# Creating a panel in the top left (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So, am I missing something?  Trying to create a panel in the top left corner, and it's not aligning properly, do this a dozen times and you will see chrome thinks the top left corner is slowly moving to the bottom right...  works fine with `type: "normal"` there a setting somewhere I need to toggle?

```
var info = {
  url: "https://www.google.com",
  type:"panel",
  width:Math.round(window.screen.availWidth*0.5),
  height:Math.round(window.screen.availHeight*0.5),
  top:0,
  left:0,
};
chrome.windows.create(info,function (callback) {});
```

Comment: Panel windows were removed from Chrome on all platforms except for ChromeOS. Try `type: 'popup'`.

Comment: on chrome OS, will try popup, thanks

Comment: same problem...

Comment: Sounds like a [bug](https://crbug.com).

Comment: Did you try on other OS? Could you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Haven't tried on another OS, will take a video

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwA2KVlVFTQtcXBpV0VxRklNems/view?usp=sharing